# must declare a named package eclipse because this compilation unit is associated to the named module

Tags: java, error-handling

I just downloaded eclipse for Java Yesterday but when I was trying to make my first program, I kept on getting this error:

> must declare a named package eclipse because this compilation unit is associated to the named module x.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Just delete *module-info.java* at your Project Explorer tab.

Comment: why does Eclipse force us to create one in the first place?

Comment: upvoted, Even though this solution works, small explanation of _why_ to delete it would be helpful.

Comment: i cannot delete it

Comment: You just create a simple new project and you run into issues, why?

Answer (score 81):

The "delete module-info.java at your Project Explorer tab" answer is the easiest and most straightforward answer, but

for those who would want a *little* more understanding or control of what's happening, the following alternate methods may be desirable;

- make an ever so slightly more realistic application; com.YourCompany.etc
  or just com.HelloWorld (Project name: com.HelloWorld and class name: HelloWorld)

or

- when creating the java project; when in the Create Java Project dialog, don't choose Finish but Next, and deselect Create module-info.java file

Answer (score 28):

**Reason of the error:** Package name left blank while creating a class. This make use of default package. Thus causes this error.

**Quick fix:**

1. Create a package eg. `helloWorld` inside the `src` folder.
2. Move `helloWorld.java` file in that package. Just drag and drop on
   the package. Error should disappear.

**Explanation:**

- My Eclipse version: *2020-09 (4.17.0)*
- My Java version: *Java 15, 2020-09-15*

Latest version of *Eclipse* required *java11* or above. The `module` feature is introduced in java9 and onward. It was proposed in 2005 for Java7 but later suspended. Java is object oriented based. And module is the moduler approach which can be seen in language like C. It was harder to implement it, due to which it took long time for the release. **Source:** [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)

**W**hen you create a new project in Eclipse then by default module feature is selected. And in Eclipse-2020-09-R, a pop-up appears which ask for creation of `module-info.java` file. If you select `don't create` then `module-info.java` will not create and your project will free from this issue.

Best practice is while crating project, after giving project name. Click on `next` button instead of `finish`. On next page at the bottom it ask for creation of `module-info.java` file. Select or deselect as per need.

**If selected:** (by default) click on `finish` button and give name for module. Now while creating a class **don't forget to give package name**. Whenever you create a class just give package name. Any name, just don't left it blank.

**If deselect:** No issue

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the "right way" to fix this issue and thoroughly explains why it happens